# No bluetooth found after Software Updater ran

Tags: bluetooth, dell, 19.10, xps

I've been running Ubuntu 19.10 on my Dell xps 9370 fine ever since it came out but today it suddenly decided that I don't have a bluetooth chipset anymore after the Software Updater did its thing.

I've tried rebooting but it didn't help so far. Any ideas how to get it up and running again?
Also curious if other people running the same Ubuntu version have ran into this problem.

Comment: ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

mrt 10 17:03:36 XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
mrt 10 17:05:05 XPS-13-9370 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.

So I found out there's a condition that's preventing the service from launching.

Comment: When adding info about a question, please click [edit] so all the facts we need are in the question itself. Please do not use Add Comment, for, as you can see, there's no formatting in Comments, no tabs or line ends. However, you did the answer AOK!

Comment: See if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241759/bluetooth-not-found-working-ubuntu-20-04-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting/rebooting apparently isn't sufficient to register the updates to the bluetooth service or drivers.
A shutdown did the trick though.