# Bluetooth not found/working Ubuntu 20.04 Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, 20.04

The problem I'm experiencing is that the wifi is working as intended, however bluetooth is simply not working or is not identifiable. I searched around, tried disabling things in bios (MOBO strix z370) but no luck. The WIFI works just fine. I'm a bit unsure how to proceed in debugging this as I am not that well versed with debugging this type of stuff. It worked fine on 18.04 and on windows, but since I installed a fresh 20.04 it stopped working.

If I try accessing via GUI I get the famous `no bluetooth found`.

[image: can't find it via GUI]

If I try accessing via bluetoothctl

```
➜  ~ bluetoothctl            
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

```
➜  ~  uname -a 
Linux borko-ubuntu 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

rfkill list does not register the device, which I assume means that the kernel is not registering the device?

```
➜  ~ rfkill list           
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
➜  ~ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

мај 20 15:10:57 borko-ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
мај 20 15:11:23 borko-ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
мај 20 15:12:15 borko-ubuntu systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

After running this I am at least able to have the service started

```
➜  ~ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth
```

```
➜  ~ sudo modprobe btusb           
➜  ~ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
➜  ~ service bluetooth status        
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-05-20 15:15:57 CEST; 1s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 7578 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38393)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─7578 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

мај 20 15:15:57 borko-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
мај 20 15:15:57 borko-ubuntu bluetoothd[7578]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
мај 20 15:15:57 borko-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
мај 20 15:15:57 borko-ubuntu bluetoothd[7578]: Starting SDP server
мај 20 15:15:57 borko-ubuntu bluetoothd[7578]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Comment: I have the same issue, running Kernel 5.3.0-53. Bluetooth wont start on resume, it needs to be turned off and started again.

Comment: Why do you think the MB has a BT device?

Comment: @Pilot6 because it worked just fine on 18.04 and on Windows, and I program bluetooth modules, so I know it worked. Plus, I have an antenna that connects directly to the MB.

Comment: I ended up installing solaar, not sure if it will help